# Changing all lowercase letters in input gradually to uppercase to get all the combinations in Batch

Tags: batch-file, uppercase, letters

I've got this problem, I want to make some kind of programm, which could change all the words to uppercase in all combinations, like (input = something -> echo something; Something; sOmething; ... sOMeTHIng; sOMeTHiNg;... SOMETHING)
Any ideas ?

Comment: Some extra considerations for getting you an accurate answer(specifically for letters appearing more than once):
1. Say the word is "test".  In your situation, is "Test" a different combination than "TesT"?
2. If there are multiple words, like "a taste", is "A tAste" different than "A taste"?

Comment: this is a kind of `permutation`, wait for [Aacini](http://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini), he may help :)

Comment: @Endoro: Thanks a lot! You have plenty confidence in me... :-)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: I realized that my first solution does not correctly manage repeated permutations caused by non-alphabetic characters, like spaces. I modified the Batch file below to fix this detail.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "input=Enter input: "

rem Convert "input" into "upcase" and "lowcase", and create "letters" string
set upcase=%input%
set lowcase=%input%
set letters=
for %%a in ("a=A" "b=B" "c=C" "d=D" "e=E" "f=F" "g=G" "h=H" "i=I" "j=J" "k=K" "l=L" "m=M"
            "n=N" "o=O" "p=P" "q=Q" "r=R" "s=S" "t=T" "u=U" "v=V" "w=W" "x=X" "y=Y" "z=Z") do (
   set upcase=!upcase:%%~a!
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set lowcase=!lowcase:%%c=%%b!
      set letters=!letters!%%c
   )
)

rem Separate individual characters in "char" two dimensional array, and create "bit" array
rem Non-alphabetic characters are marked with "bit" elements = 2
set n=-1
:nextChar
   set /A n+=1
   set char=%lowcase:~0,1%
   if "!letters:%char%=!" neq "%letters%" (
      set bit[%n%]=0
      set char[%n%,0]=%char%
      set char[%n%,1]=%upcase:~0,1%
   ) else (
      set bit[%n%]=2
      set char[%n%,2]=%char%
   )
   set upcase=%upcase:~1%
   set lowcase=%lowcase:~1%
if defined lowcase goto nextChar

rem Generate all permutations
:nextValue
   rem Copy characters from "char" array into "output" string with current "bit" values
   set output=
   for /L %%i in (0,1,%n%) do (
      for %%b in (!bit[%%i]!) do (
         set output=!output!!char[%%i,%%b]!
      )
   )
   rem Show this permutation
   echo %output%
   rem Advance "bit" array to next value
   set /A b=n+1, carry=1
   :nextBit
      set /A b-=1
      if !bit[%b%]! lss 2 (
         if !bit[%b%]! equ 0 (
            set /A bit[%b%]=1, carry=0
         ) else (
            set /A bit[%b%]=0, carry=1
         )
      )
   if %b% gtr 0 if %carry% equ 1 goto nextBit
if %carry% equ 0 goto nextValue
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. You saved lots of my time :)

Comment: @MichalHerobrineSeják: Well, if you think this answer solved your question, you may accept it as Best answer... :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution properly handles characters in string that do not have case.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "string=%~1"
set "permutation="
set pos=0

for %%C in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do set "lower_%%C=%%C"
for %%C in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do set "upper_%%C=%%C"

if defined string call :permute
exit /b

:permute
setlocal
set "chr=!string:~%pos%,1!"
if not defined chr (
  echo(!permutation!
  exit /b
)
set /a pos+=1
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%C in ("!chr!") do (
  if defined upper_%%C (
    set "permutation=!permutation!!lower_%%C!"
    call :permute
    set "permutation=!permutation:~0,-1!!upper_%%C!"
    call :permute
  ) else (
    set "permutation=!permutation!%%C"
    call :permute
  )
)
exit /b
```

Assuming script is PERMUTE.BAT, here is a sample call with output:

```
>permute.bat "test it"
test it
test iT
test It
test IT
tesT it
tesT iT
tesT It
tesT IT
teSt it
teSt iT
teSt It
teSt IT
teST it
teST iT
teST It
teST IT
tEst it
tEst iT
tEst It
tEst IT
tEsT it
tEsT iT
tEsT It
tEsT IT
tESt it
tESt iT
tESt It
tESt IT
tEST it
tEST iT
tEST It
tEST IT
Test it
Test iT
Test It
Test IT
TesT it
TesT iT
TesT It
TesT IT
TeSt it
TeSt iT
TeSt It
TeSt IT
TeST it
TeST iT
TeST It
TeST IT
TEst it
TEst iT
TEst It
TEst IT
TEsT it
TEsT iT
TEsT It
TEsT IT
TESt it
TESt iT
TESt It
TESt IT
TEST it
TEST iT
TEST It
TEST IT
```